# Find the cell reference in a text string in a range

Tags: excel, function

I have a problem which Ive been trying to solve right now for a few days, but Im kind of desperate because I cannot seem to find the solution.

The situation is that I want to know the cell references of Apple, in the following example:

Column A

1. Kiwi Banana
2. Apple Orange
3. Grapefruit Kiwi
4. Banana Pineapple
5. Pear Lemon
6. Apple Kiwi

So when I fill in the formula, the outcome is that Apple can be found in A2 and A6.

I did figure out that I should use the function:

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH($C$1,$A$1:$A$6,0)+ROW(x)-1,COLUMN(x),4)
```

However, I do not know what to fill in at the *row* and *column* parts. Since a lookup needs to be conducted, in a range and should be found in a string of text.Find

Hopefully you can help me out!

Comment: Maybe using VBA macros is a better way to achieve this rather than 'plain' excel formulas.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of things that might get you back on track.

First, the "match" function is capable of supporting wildcards, so instead of `MATCH($C$1,$A$1:$A$6,0)`, you could use `MATCH("*"&$C$1&"*",$A$1:$A$6,0)`.

Second, since you want multiple results, it's a poor fit for a formula in a single cell.  Instead, you could approach the problem by adding a column that determines whether the cell in the same row matches your key word.  I like to make formulas like these return a 1 or 0 so they sum up neatly.  You could use a formula like this in D1 and copy down.  `=1-1*ISERR(FIND($C$1,A1))`

Finally, if you want to collate your results into a single cell, you can use the "textjoin" formula.  So, let's say you've added a column in E like `=IF(D1=1,"A"&ROW(A1),"")`, that says "A2" or "A6" or blank, then you could describe your results in a single cell with the forumula, `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,$E$1:$E$6)`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the issue of returning the address, there is also the issue of differentiating "apple" from "pineapple".  The following formula does both.

`myRng` is the range where your information is located.
The format of your strings is as you show in your example (space separated).

Note that in the formula we have a space before and after `the Fruit`, and also before and after each entry in the range.

With your data in column A, and your "fruit" in C1, try this formula in any cell, and fill down until you see blanks:

```
=IFERROR(ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(15,6,1/ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" " & $C$1 & " "," " & myRng & " "))*ROW(myRng),ROWS($1:1)),COLUMN(myRng)),"")
```

[image]

`Search` is used as it is case-insensitive.  If you want a case-sensitive match, use `Find`.

`Aggregate` enables using the `Small` function and also ignoring errors. The array upon which it is acting will be an array of sequential Error values (`DIV/0`) and Row numbers.

I suggest you use the Formula Evaluation tool to examine how the formula works.